# Scrollview not scroll inside PanResonder in react native

Tags: ios, react-native, scrollview

Im use this library react-native-swipe-gestures to listen to swipe left and right and inside it i have scrollview but not work ,
 i search in the problem and i found that PanResonder prevent other interactions  which implement in react-native-swipe-gestures library 
code example  :

```
        <GestureRecognizer
                // onSwipeUp={(state) =>{}}
                // onSwipeDown={(state) =>{}}
                onSwipeLeft={(state) => this.onSwipeLeft(state)}
                onSwipeRight={(state) => this.onSwipeRight(state)}
                config={{
                    velocityThreshold: 0.5,
                    directionalOffsetThreshold: 100
                }}
                style={Styles.baseContainer}   >

   <ScrollView onScroll={() => console.log('scrolled')} 
               style={styles.scroll_view} >
          <Text style={{fontSize:96}}>Scroll this</Text>
          <Text style={{fontSize:96}}>Scroll this</Text>
          <Text style={{fontSize:96}}>Scroll this</Text>
          <Text style={{fontSize:96}}>Scroll this</Text>
          <Text style={{fontSize:96}}>Scroll this</Text>
        </ScrollView>
</GestureRecognizer>
```

i need to fix this issue !!